Combinatorics, Calculate probability of drawing tiles
I have a tile drawing problem that I'd like to work out that I don't know how to approach:

There are 14 tiles in a bag.
There are 3 tiles that are marked "jackpot".
There are 2 tiles that are marked "lose".

The player must draw 3 tiles, drawing one at a time, and if any drawn tile is market "lose", then the drawing stops and he has to pay a loser's fee. If he draws all 3 tiles and no "lose" tile is drawn, and one of the 3 tiles is marked "jackpot", then he gets the jackpot. The game is over at this point (to play again, the bag is refilled, and the game starts over with the same rules). What is the percentage chance of getting "jackpot" and the percentage chance of getting "lose"?
If the player is to draw 1 tile only, it is very easy to work out the probability of getting "jackpot" or "lose", 3 out of 14 are "jackpot" (so 3/14 * 100 = 21.43%) and 2 out of 14 are "lose" (so 2/14 * 100 = 14.29%). It's when there is more than one draw, and a stop condition, that I'm lost on where to start in calculating it. I've had variations of this come up in work and other situations, so I would really appreciate knowing how to approach this type of problem where there are multiple factors like this.

What happens if they get nothing? (I'm confused because you specify the "drawing stops." It seems, as described, it always stops. If you mean they draw three sequentially, then say so, but definitely say what happens when you don't lose or win the jackpot after drawing the third tile.

It looks ambiguous if the third drawn tile is Lose and yet one of the first two tiles is Jackpot. Because you've "drawn three tiles and one of them is jackpot." But you also match the "lose" criterion. This kind of problem requires careful writing. Only the human meanings of "lose" and "jackpot" implies they are likely disjoint events.

Ah, I see what you mean, I said "The player must draw 3 tiles", but I did not say "The player must draw 3 tiles, one at a time". I will update, thanks.

I've updated the question. The tiles are drawn one after another, and checked upon drawing. If one tile says "lose" then the drawing stops, no other tiles are dawn. "lose" here actually means that you lose money (i.e. you have to pay something), so there are 3 possible states, "win", "nothing happens", or "lose".

Yes, but if nothing happens, do you have a next round of three tiles drawn ?

You possibly could have another round, but the bag is refilled, and it is a new game, so the same conditions apply. Thanks for pointing these things out. I see that the rules needed more clarity.

The 'Stop' condition is boring you. We can say that we draw 3 tiles, we look at the 3 tiles. If at least one of them is 'lose', we loose. It is exactly the same game as original one, and there is no 'stop' condition.

Maybe that's true. It just seemed to me that as we draw the three tiles sequentially, the probabilities change on each sequential draw, but I did already consider what you are saying, e.g. 'jackpot', 'lose', 'jackpot' would be a virtual state that would never be seen because the 'lose' condition stops the draws but is required to calculate all states. I tried to calculate on that basis, with virtual states being equivalent to 'lose', but somehow came up with the wrong answer (with 'lose' having a 55% chance). On the other hand, I see that Daniel's solution adds up to 100%.

The probability of not drawing a 'lose' tile is $\frac{12}{14}\times\frac{11}{13}\times\frac{10}{12}=\frac{55}{91}$
Subtracting this value from $1$ gives us the probability of drawing a 'lose' tile: $\frac{36}{91}$
The probability of drawing 'nothing' is $\frac{9}{14}\times\frac{8}{13}\times\frac{7}{12}=\frac{21}{91}$
The probability of drawing a 'jackpot' tile without drawing a 'lose' is the difference between not drawing a 'lose' tile and drawing 'nothing': $\frac{55}{91}-\frac{21}{91}=\frac{34}{91}$

Thanks. Do you know why the approach of looking at each possible outcome, calculating the outcome, and then summing across them for each scenario does not work (as was proposed in the other answer that was deleted)? For the probability of drawing nothing, I follow your logic, but I have a nagging feeling that the 'stop' condition interferes with this in some way (I don't know how, maybe I'm just wrong, but it's bothering me - possibly it's that your calculation just feels "too easy"...).

[1] The trouble is that you have written "the player must draw 3 tiles. [2] Also, a new query that has arisen in my mind is that is just one game to be played, or game after game played  until a definite conclusion (win or lose) is reached ? (I have given a solution for this interpretation, too)

"must draw 3 tiles" is qualified by "unless the 'lose' tile is drawn at any point", yes. The real-world situation would confuse things further - there are scenarios where if a 'lose' tile is drawn, it is removed for the next run, but any 'jackpot' or 'neutral' tiles would be returned - but I don't want to complicate things, and this answer is great; using the technique in this post, I am now able to make any later calculations myself easily, so these techniques are very useful for me.

Yea, it's a nice clean answer !

I used your technique here and extrapolated to 2, 3, 4, 5 draws, but it's left me confused. The following are [P(J no L),  P(N no L), P(L)]. 1-draw[21.43%, 64.29%, 14.29%], 2-draws[33.00%, 39.56%, 27.48%], 3-draws[37.36%, 23.08%, 39.56%], 4-draws[36.86%, 12.59%, 50.55%], 5-draws[54.15%, 6.29%, 60.55%]. The issue is that P[J no L] goes from 3-draw 37.36% down to 4-draw 36.86%, and then back up to 54.15% for 5-draw, and I can't work out why?

@YorSubs Your 5-draw results total over 120%, Your error: $54.15=60.44-6.29$ You subtracted P(N) from P(L) instead of P(N) from P(no L). $100-60.44-6.29=33.27$

Thank you Daniel, my bad. My second concern is to do with the relative values of P(J) vs P(N). I'm probably misunderstanding something again, but it seems unlikely to me that the probability of P(J no L) can be higher than that of P(N no L), as there are only 3 Jackpot tiles compared to 9 neutral tiles. But that's what I'm seeing with 3, 4, and 5 draws, where it is 37.36% vs 23.08% for 3, 36.86% vs 12.59% for 4, and 33.27% vs 6.29% for 5 draws. How can we explain that if there are only 3 J tiles and 9 N tiles?

@YorSubs P(N) isn't just no L, it is also no J. Your observation is that you are more likely to draw a mix of N and J than to draw only N.

Alternative approach: work combinatorically.
Probability of not losing is
$$A = \frac{\binom{12}{3}}{\binom{14}{3}}.$$
So, probability of losing is $~1 - A.$
Probability of neither losing nor winning is
$$B = \frac{\binom{9}{3}}{\binom{14}{3}}.$$
So, since the events of losing, winning, and neither winning nor losing are mutually exclusive, the probability of winning is
$$1 - (1 - A) - B = A - B = \frac{\binom{12}{3} - \binom{9}{3}}{\binom{14}{3}}.$$

With the clarifications you have given about sequential draws of three and possible results, we can forget about "no result" because you say that for the next round, the bag is refilled, so it's the same game repeated
Then you could have the following sequences and results, with J for Jackpot, L for lose and N for neutral:
$1.\; J \quad Pr = \frac{3}{14}$
$2.\; NJ \quad Pr = \frac9{14}\frac3{13}$
$3. \; NNJ \quad Pr = \frac9{14}\frac{8}{13}\frac3{12}$
Add up  to get $W$, say
similarly work out for lose, you should be able to do so, and after adding up, let's call this $L$
Now $W:L$ will represent the odds in favor of win (no result won't matter as a fresh round will be played)
Thus $P(win) = \dfrac{W}{W+L}$
$\underline{\texttt{Remarks}}$
Note that W+L will not add up to $1$ because we didn't compute N. So we avoided the drudgery of computing N by using odds
PS:
One interpretation is that even if a win is there on the first draw , you may lose if there is a "lose" in the $3$ drawn. Ok, just a bit of modification is needed then, surely you have got the idea now ?
If not, ask, else I'll  assume that now you can now compute it easily.
A doubt I get about this interpretation is why specify * sequential draws if even after drawing "jackpot, "lose" ruins ?
PPS:
Anyway, if I take "sequential" has no importance, we can easily solve using combinations
$P(No\; result) = \dfrac{\binom93}{\binom{14}3} = \dfrac{21}{91}$
$P(Lose)   = 1- P(not\; lose)$
$= 1 - \dfrac{\binom{12}3}{\binom{14}3}  = \dfrac{36}{91}$
and by subtraction
$P(Win) = 1 - \dfrac{21+36}{91}= \dfrac{34}{91}$

Morning Thoughts
The above results are the probabilities for one game. If games are going to be played until a definite conclusion is to be reached through  either a Win or a Loss, the answer will change.
$$P(Ultimately\;win)=\frac{34}{91}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \left(\frac{21}{91}\right)^n= \frac{17}{35}$$

Winning the prize requires three draws, and you can lose after drawing a jackpot tile.

@DanielMathias: Such a confusing problem statement with s many revisons. Ok, so I shall revise again, thanks !

Thanks, and sorry for the confusion; it's a real scenario that came up in a real-world situation. I've found all of this very useful and fascinating.

Glad to be of some help. But if it is a real life scenario, you should think a bit, and describe it $\texttt{precisely}$. Are none of the answers addressing the problem ?

I marked the other as answer, just as it's simpler to calculate. I did indeed miss some important points in the original OP, thanks for highlighting the issues.

That's fine, good that you are satisfied !
